# what is $ \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$

Tags: probability

Quick question.

I know that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n$ is a set come from sequence ${A_n}$, 
but  $ \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$ the $P(A_n)$ is a number not a set , so what does the $\liminf$ mean to the sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers then $\lim \inf a_n$ is defined as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \{a_m: m \geq n\}$.